# "Earthquake": When to use "temblor" and "terremoto"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, uso-de-palabras

When referring to an *earthquake*, are `temblor` and `terremoto` perfect synonyms? Are there any differences?

Answer (score 6):

The main distinction is generally in terms of *magnitude*.  `temblors` are generally lighter eathquakes that cause little to no damage. (See: [temblor - Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/temblor#Spanish).) On the other hand a `terremoto` is usally a more severe earthquake. As a rough approximation I'd say anything below a 6.5 on the Richter scale would probably be called a `temblor`, while anything stronger would be refered to as a `terremoto`.

A second distinction that is also important to note is that while `terremoto` specifically refers to earthquakes (e.g. shifting and vibrations that come from *within the earth*), a `temblor` could be any type of shaking (of the ground.)

**For Example:**

> ○   La explosión de la bomba fue tan fuerte que un *temblor* que duró más de 10 segundos resultó! => *The explosion of the bomb was so strong, that a quake (of the earth) that lasted more than 10 seconds resulted.*
>
> X   La explosión de la bomba fue tan fuerte que un *terremoto* que duró más de 10 segundos resultó! => *The explosion of the bomb was so strong, that a (seismic) quake that lasted more than 10 seconds resulted.*

The second sentence in the above example sounds a bit awkward (but it might be acceptable depending on regional usage.)

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 6):

Para mí, la diferencia más importante entre terremoto y temblor es que la primera se refiere inequívocamente al fenómeno geológico, mientras que la segunda es mucho menos específica, y por tanto puede hacer referencia a más significados. Sin contexto, o sin un contexto claro, "temblor" debe estar seguida de "de tierra", para que sea interpretada inequívocamente como  terremoto.

Answer (score 3):

A *temblor* is a low-intensity *terremoto*; therefore, in the general case, an earthquake is a *terremoto.*

Answer (score 1):

Antes que todo, existen muchas formas aceptadas para referirse a los terremotos: movimiento telúrico, sismo, seísmo, temblor, sacudida, temblor de tierra.

En el español culto informal son sinónimos, en el español de América Latina se hace una diferencia en cuanto a la magnitud del movimiento para Temblor o Terremoto.

> temblor
>   De temblar.
>   1. m. Acción y efecto de temblar.
>   2. m. Terremoto de escasa intensidad.
>   3. m. Am. terremoto (‖ sacudida de la corteza terrestre).
>   temblor de tierra
>   1. m. terremoto (‖ sacudida de la corteza terrestre).

Por otro lado, terremoto, hace referencia a la acción simple del movimiento de tierra sin considerar magnitud, según la RAE:

> terremoto
>   Del lat. terraemōtus.
>   1. m. Sacudida violenta de la corteza y manto terrestres, ocasionada por fuerzas que actúan en el interior de la Tierra.
>   2. m. Conmoción ocasionada por un suceso grave o inesperado.
>   3. m. coloq. Persona inquieta, o que se mueve mucho.

Pero, lo correcto es decir sismo o seísmo. (RAE)

> seísmo
>   Del fr. séisme, y este del gr. σεισμός seismós.
>   1. m. terremoto (‖ sacudida de la corteza terrestre). U. t. en sent. fig.

o

> sismo
>   Del gr. σεισμός seismós.
>   1. m. terremoto (‖ sacudida de la corteza terrestre).

En mi país, Chile, el que tiene el triste récord de ser el país con más actividad sísmica en el mundo, se hace la diferencia entre temblor y terremoto cuando pasa los 7.5 Richter. 
Tienes que tomar en consideración el contexto local en dónde se use la palabra temblor y terremoto, porque en Europa, Centro América, Estados Unidos, a sismos de 4.5 Richter son considerados como terremotos en el lenguaje formal.

Comment: Claro, es relativo. Ayer precisamente hubo un movimiento telúrico de 7.1 grados. Las noticias en medios extranjeros dicen "terremoto". Acá en Chile ni por asomo le diríamos así. Fue un "temblor fuerte", un "sismo" o un "remezón".  El terremoto de Italia del 2016 fue de 6.5, lo que acá habría sido un temblor.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, there are actually 3 terms in Spanish: "Temblores", "Sismos", and "Terremotos".

"Temblor(es)" and "Sismo(s)" are interchangeable and depending on the country it might be more common to use one or the other. 
These both refer to earthquakes that cause little to no societal/economic damage (e.g. deaths, injuries, property damage, etc.)

Earthquakes are deemed "Terremotos" when they cause considerable societal/economic damage.

However, as Miguel noted "Temblores" can refer to any shaking of the ground, whereas "Sismos" and "Temblores" are geological events.